# get current user LanguageLocaleKey in javascript

Tags: visualforce

Ii want to display Javascript alert when changes made in one tab are not saved and user moves to next tab. I am using the following code but nothing is displayed when i checked condition for language. Without this condition alert is displayed when user moves from one tab to another.

```
<scripttype="text/javascript" src="/soap/ajax/27.0/connection.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
var sid = getCookie('sid');
var server = "https://" + window.location.host + "/services/Soap/u/27.0";
  //initiate the connection
sforce.connection.init(sid, server);

var currentUser = sforce.connection.getUserInfo();
var result = sforce.connection.query('select LanguageLocaleKey from User where      id=\''+currentUser.getUserId+'\'');
var tab1 = document.getElementById('PPage:T1');
var tab2 = document.getElementById('PPage:T2');
var tab3 = document.getElementById('PPage:T3');
var tab4 = document.getElementById('PPage:T4');
var tab5 = document.getElementById('corpgridphone');
//alert('tabs '+tab1 +tab2 +tab3 +tab4);
var save1 = document.getElementsByName("inlineEditSave");
var cancel1 = document.getElementsByName("inlineEditCancel");
var edit2 = document.getElementById('PPage:ActformId:Actpg:Actpgb:EditButton');
var edit3 = document.getElementById('PPage:IntformId:Intpg:Intpgb:EditButton1');
var edit4 = document.getElementById('PPage:CLIformId:CLIpg:CLIpgb:EditButton2');
//alert('Edit Buttons '+edit2 +edit3 +edit4);
tab1.onclick = function() {
    if(edit2.style.display == 'none'){
    if(result == 'fr')
            {
                alert('S'il vous pla&#236;t enregistrer les modifications dans l'onglet D&#233;tails');
            }
            else if(result == 'en_US')
            {
            alert('Please save the changes in Accounts tab');}
            return false;
    }   
    if(edit3.style.display == 'none'){
    if(result == 'fr')
            {
                alert('S'il vous pla&#236;t enregistrer les modifications dans l'onglet D&#233;tails');
            }
            else if(result == 'en_US')
            {
            alert('Please save the changes in Interests tab');}
            return false;
    }
    if(edit4.style.display == 'none'){
    if(result == 'fr')
            {
                alert('S'il vous pla&#236;t enregistrer les modifications dans l'onglet D&#233;tails');
            }
            else if(result == 'en_US')
            {
            alert('Please save the changes in Client Information tab');}
            return false;
    }

}
tab2.onclick = function() {
    if(save1[0].style.display == 'inline'){
    if(result == 'fr')
            {
                alert('S'il vous pla&#236;t enregistrer les modifications dans l'onglet D&#233;tails');
            }
            else if(result == 'en_US')
            {
            alert('Please save the changes in Details tab');}
            return false;
    }       
    if(edit3.style.display == 'none'){
    if(result == 'fr')
            {
                alert('S'il vous pla&#236;t enregistrer les modifications dans l'onglet D&#233;tails');
            }
            else if(result == 'en_US')
            {
            alert('Please save the changes in Interests tab');}
            return false;
    }       

    if(edit4.style.display == 'none'){
    if(result == 'fr')
            {
                alert('S'il vous pla&#236;t enregistrer les modifications dans l'onglet D&#233;tails');
            }
            else if(result == 'en_US')
            {
            alert('Please save the changes in Client Information tab');}
            return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is in the context of Visualforce, you would do well to simply have this exposed in the controller:

```
String userLanguage;

public String getLanguageLocaleKey() {
    if(userLanguage == null) {
        userLanguage = [SELECT LanguageLocaleKey FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()].LanguageLocaleKey;
    }
    return userLanguage;
}
```

This avoids the need to waste an API call just to the the user language when this information is freely available by querying it in your controller.

I would also recommend using a translation table instead of a convoluted if statement.

```
var messages = { 
    message1: { 
        fr: "S'il vous pla&#236;t enregistrer les modifications dans l'onglet D&#233;tails',
        en_US: "Please save the changes in Accounts tab"
    },
    message2: {
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

You can then display the error like this:

```
if(edit2.style.display == 'none') { 
    alert(messages.message1[languageLocaleKey]); 
    return false; 
}
```

This centralizes your logic to just a small portion of code, and you can fix translations.

Also, note that you're not escaping your strings correctly in the example code; this should cause errors. Use double-quotes, or make sure you escape the strings correctly.

Finally, you could choose to avoid this entire mess by simply using [Custom Labels](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cl_about.htm&language=en_US), which are precisely designed to support this need without your page having to know what language the user is configured for (the system renders them automatically for you!).